# Kdevelop in Windows XP

Tags: linux, ide, windows-xp, portability, kdevelop

I received a src archive from a friend who develops Qt apps on Linux on Kdevelop IDE. Is it possible to load the Kdevelop project in Windows  in some IDE ? Is there a Kdevelop port on Windows without Cygwin/Msys etc ? Are there any workarounds or I should I have to install Linux and take charge?

Update : I visited the [page](http://www.kdevelop.org/mediawiki/index.php/KDevelop_4#Microsoft_Windows) as mentioned in the below answer, but  there's no Kdevelop package in the KdeWin installer . See [here](http://tinypic.com/r/ne7vjc/6)

Comment: Do you want to develop or do just want to compile?

Answer (score 2):

KDevelop 4 will also be available on Windows (together with a lot of other KDE4 software). It is currently in beta, but you can [download a Windows installer](http://www.kdevelop.org/mediawiki/index.php/KDevelop_4#Microsoft_Windows). The installer also lets you install other KDE4 software and should come with the QT development files you will need to develop QT applications.

Comment: Can i import a Kdevelop project done in Linux on the Windows version?

Comment: I would think so, if the Project is created by a similar version of KDevelop there, but I haven't tried it. How well it will compile also is a different question, depending on if the project sticks with Qt or uses system specific libraries/functions. I'd say your best bet it to just try it.

Comment: there's no Kdevelop package in the KdeWin installer

Comment: You have to use an unstable mirror.  Just enter http://www.winkde.org/pub/kde/ports/win32/releases/nightly/20110313/.  http://www.winkde.org/pub/kde/ports/win32/releases/unstable/4.2.95/, too.  These go in the mirror after unchecking "skip needed functionality.  Never have this check-marked.  But we defautly check mark it for you anyways"

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, there is no port to Windows of Kdevelop4 and Kdevelop3 was run with cygwin - which, IMHO, is not really a robust solution.

It would probably be easier, and better, to install a Linux distro in a virtual machine and go at it from there. If you don't need access to Windows, you could just install a Linux on a separate hardrive and/or partition.

Answer (score 0):

Install linux on virtual machine such as *vmware* or *virtual box*.